# Click on different html class with the same name

Tags: java, selenium

I have an html radiobox with Yes or Not choice.
But the Yes and Not class have the same class name.

CODE FOR YES

```
<div class="quantumWizTogglePaperradioRadioContainer"><div class="quantumWizTogglePaperradioOffRadio exportOuterCircle"><div class="quantumWizTogglePaperradioOnRadio exportInnerCircle"></div></div></div>
```

CODE FOR NOT

```
<div class="quantumWizTogglePaperradioRadioContainer"><div class="quantumWizTogglePaperradioOffRadio exportOuterCircle"><div class="quantumWizTogglePaperradioOnRadio exportInnerCircle"></div></div></div>
```

When I use this code, the program click on the first one in the radiobox form.

```
radioButton = String.format("//div[@class='quantumWizTogglePaperradioOffRadio exportOuterCircle']");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(radioButton)).click();
```

how can I recognize them?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest using absolute XPath rather than relative XPath it might resolve it. please see below how absolute XPath is different from relative using the google search bar.

```
Relative XPath - `//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input`
absolute XPath - `/html/body/div/div[3]/form/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input`
```

or you can use the reference of other elements, For example, suppose if you have a div before with yes and no option with id="Radiobutton". you can still recognize yes and no  as below as

yes - `//*[@id="Radiobutton"]/div[1]`
No - `//*[@id="Radiobutton"]/div[2]`

Let me know if you need any clarification

[image]

[image: Actual Website look]

You can see above the radio button I can give you an example with that. so we are trying to get possible Paths for radio buttons in div highlighted in black. similar to your problem it has the same class name. so below are the some of possible ways to do it

1. relative XPath Using Form id which is up in the hierarchy

   ```
   Yes - `//*[@id="create-form"]/div[3]/div/div/div/ul/li/div[2]/div/div/div[1]`
   No - `//*[@id="create-form"]/div[3]/div/div/div/ul/li/div[2]/div/div/div[2]`
   ```
2. Using Absolute path - the absolute path is tracking hierarchy from top to the element. In this case it will be

   ```
   Yes - `/html/body/div/section/div/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div/div/div/ul/li/div[2]/div/div/div[1]`

   No - `/html/body/div/section/div/div/div/div/form/div[3]/div/div/div/ul/li/div[2]/div/div/div[2]`
   ```

If you see the difference here between 1 and 2. In absolute path instead of starting from form id as a reference, it starts right from HTML tag and tracks the element in DOM tree.

Comment: Can you show me, please, One example with Absolute Xpath in my case, how should it be my code for Yes or Not radiobutton?

Comment: I can help but you need to give me a bigger snapshot of DOM containing root to the element or a link would be better, also a note try capturing XPath with firefox browser copy XPath feature in most case it gives absolute XPath.

Comment: I edited my answer by adding an example. Hope it clarifies your doubt

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 2 radiobox, use this in the order

First radiobox :

```
radioButton = String.format("(//div[@class='quantumWizTogglePaperradioOffRadio exportOuterCircle'])[1]");
```

Second radiobox :

```
radioButton = String.format("(//div[@class='quantumWizTogglePaperradioOffRadio exportOuterCircle'])[2]");
```